# Using maps with MarkLogic in xquery

Tags: arrays, stack, maps, xquery, marklogic

I am trying to create stack data structure in xquery using maps so I declared the map in the stack file as following :

```
declare namespace map = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/map";
```

but it gives me an error after some search I figured out that the namespace has been changed but still I don't know the new one, I tried  "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/endpoints/map_DELETE_IF_UNUSED" but it gives me an error in normal array variable deceleration which is in another file, the line that gives me  the error

```
declare variable $Arr_Of_C_DataTypes := ["C","S"];
```

Error: XQST0059: Imported module's namespace does not match requested namespace

does anyone knows the cause of this I guess the namespace still wrong but I don't know why it gives me this with array deceleration which is in another file the array deceleration is

```
declare namespace array = "http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array";
```

the code for using maps to create stack

```
declare function stack:new($seq as item()*) as map(*) {
    map:new((map:entry("stack",$seq)))
};

declare function stack:push($stack as map(*),$item as item()) {
    map:put($stack,"stack",($item,map:get($stack,"stack")))
};

declare function stack:pop($stack as map(*)) as item() {
    let $stack-seq := map:get($stack,"stack")
    let $head := fn:head($stack-seq)
    let $_ := map:put($stack,"stack",fn:tail($stack-seq))
    return $head
};

declare function stack:show($stack as map(*)) as item()* {
    map:get($stack,"stack")
};
```

Comment: Map functions are built-in, so no need to declare namespace or import anything: https://docs.marklogic.com/map. Could you show some more code, not quite clear what you are trying to do...

Comment: I edited the question but when I delete the maps deceleration this error appears : XPST0081: Namespace prefix 'map' has not been declared

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to use XQuery 3 features that are not supported by MarkLogic. I recommend using version declaration "1.0-ml" inside MarkLogic together with using earlier mentioned map:map for maps, and https://docs.marklogic.com/json:array for stacks..

Comment: so you mean I should use lower version of xquery ? I tried to change the version to 1.0 and changed the map{*} to map:map but another error appeared   XPST0051: Unknown simple type map:map and without declaring map it does not recognise map word in map:map

Comment: Are you using "1.0-ml" in your declaration? This has the example https://docs.marklogic.com/map:map with the correct declaration on the first line.

Comment: no I'm not using it, when I tried using :  xquery version "1.0-ml";
 it gives me an error XQST0031: Invalid XQuery version 1.0-ml

Comment: Are you sure you are using MarkLogic?